# mysql order by datetime not working?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to order a query by datetime (newest first) but it seems to be returned completely unsorted, here is the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (some_value = '$id' OR some_value Like '%$id_multi%') ORDER BY (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_datetime)) DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql)
```

the "OR" clause is definitely what is causing the error in the sorting because i use the same query elsewhere in my api without an OR clause that returns perfectly sorted. I have tried changing the query in all sorts of ways, but get no results what so ever. Is there a better way to go about this? Any help is greatly appreciated

**Edit**

$id is an integer and $id_multi is a comma delimited integer i.e.

```
$id = 25;
$id_multi = "," . $id . ",";
```

an example entry's some_value column could be: `,12,25,13,`

Comment: What are you passing in `id_multi` argument?? And also explain with sample input and output data

Comment: basically it $id_multi = "," . $id . "," in other words im querying where some_value = $id or contains $id.

Comment: I fit is comma separated list of ids then you can use FIND_IN_SET() function rather then using OR opereator

Comment: @SaharshShah im not familiar with that function, could you by chance give me a quick example? so i don't mess up the syntax or something

Answer (score 0):

Check [**FIND_IN_SET()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$id', some_value) 
ORDER BY created_datetime DESC
```

Comment: this is only returning the entries where some_value = '$id'

Comment: that return all of them, but sadly still not sorted.

Comment: @justinshores What is the datatype of created_datetime column.

Comment: it is a datetime column

Comment: @justinshores Check the updated answer. if you still not able to find the result then provide your sample structure with sample input data with desired output.

Answer (score -1):

Try belowone

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE some_value = '$id' OR some_value in  '(%$id_multi%)' ORDER BY created_datetime DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql)
```

If that is also not working please tell datatype of created_datetime

Also provide output of `echo $sql;`

Your problem is actually simple. In order to work query it should be something like

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE some_value = '7' OR some_value in  (21,34,51) ORDER BY created_datetime DESC
```

after substituting variables. If your avoided `(` or `,` or `)` You will get syntax error. i hope you got your problem now.

In order to check this error i requested output of `echo $sql` . if you provide that i'll give you the exact syntax error

Your problem is your not passing `in  '(%$id_multi%)'` properly, after substituting values it should be something like `(12,13,65)`

Comment: No that was how i had it originally sorry, the parenthesis were added as part of my trying to figure it out, and the data type is datetime

Comment: @justin shores- please provide output of echo $sql;

Comment: id is an integer and multi id is a comma delimited integer i.e. 25 and ,25, respectively

Comment: @justinshores - got it check new answer. if that also not working please provide echo $sql  result;

Comment: @justinshores - did you checked new answer? I know what is the exact problem, please share echo $sql output

Comment: yes all that does is break the like part of the query

Comment: no disabling half the query isnt solving the problem

Comment: @justinshores - modified answer, please check